# What is the equivelant of the Excel function ROUNDDOWN(number, num_digits) in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, rounding

As the title suggests I need a C# equivelant of ROUNDDOWN.

For example, if you take the figure 13.608000, the output i am looking for is 13.60.

I can't seem to find anything that covers exactly what I am after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
var rounded = Math.Floor(13.608000 * 100) / 100;
```

Note that Math.Floor() rounds down to the nearest integer, hence the need to multiply, round down, and then divide.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a direct port of the Excel function for variable number of decimal places

```
public double RoundDown(double number, int decimalPlaces)
{
    return Math.Floor(number * Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces)) / Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);
}
```

e.g.  RoundDown (13.608000,2) = 13.60, RoundDown(12345,-3) = 12000,

Answer (score 3):

Here's the right solution:

```
    double RoundDown(double value, int digits)
    {
        if (value >= 0)
            return Math.Floor(value * Math.Pow(10, digits)) / Math.Pow(10, digits);

        return Math.Ceiling(value * Math.Pow(10, digits)) / Math.Pow(10, digits);
    }
```

RichardW1001's answer is almost right, he just didn't account for the rounding of negative values.

Comment: This does not work in the same way as RoundDown in Excel which seems to round -ve values up towards zero e.g.
-2.55 becomes -2, this function will round -2.55 to -3.

Comment: If you're working with Angular DecimalPipe, this is what you'll want for your back-end equivalent calculation.

Answer (score 0):

For rounding down, use Math.Floor.  To round off to a different factor than 1.0, multiply before calling Floor and divide afterwards.

```
double x = 0.01 * Math.Floor(100 * y);
```

Answer (score -1):

Math.Round function should do it, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx

Comment: <quote>The behavior of this method follows IEEE Standard 754, section 4. This kind of rounding is sometimes called rounding to nearest</quote>  Question asked about rounding **down**.

Comment: Not quite, because it does not always round down.

Answer (score -1):

Workaround:

```
decimal x = 13.6080001;
int places = 2;
int result = (int)(Math.Round(x - (0.5 * Math.Pow(10, 0 - places), places)));
```